# The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-image-picker

I want to show updated image but I get this error **The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider?'.**

Please solve my error

Here is my code

```
File?_image; 
CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 70,
                              backgroundImage:_image!=null?FileImage(_image!.absolute) : NetworkImage(snapshot.data!.docs[index]["imageurl"]),
                            ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply just cast as the image provider

```
backgroundImage:_image!=null?FileImage(_image!.absolute) : NetworkImage(snapshot.data!.docs[index]["imageurl"]) as ImageProvider,
```